# How can I download a file using AppleScript?

Tags: applescript

Something like:

```
set the file_tgt to (path to downloads as string) as file specification
    set file_src to "http://my_file.png"
    tell application "URL Access Scripting"
        download file_src to file_tgt
    end tell
```

1. How do I get the path to the default downloads folder for the user?
2. AppleScript doesn't like the path conversion. How can I fix that?

Comment: Important to note the "URL Access Scripting" is not available for over a decade now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution myself:

1. [Use "path to downloads folder"](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-DontLinkElementID_760)
2. `set the file_tgt to (path to downloads folder as string) & "file.png"`

Answer (score 0):

To download a collection of files hosted in a directory using applescript and shell script -

```
set counter to 0
repeat 36 times
    do shell script "curl -f 'http://stage.omatics.com/Images/Devices/Devices/" & counter & ".png' -o ~/Desktop/" & counter & ".png"
    set counter to counter + 10
    delay 2
end repeat
```

This will download these 36 files

```
http://stage.omatics.com/Images/Devices/Devices/0.png
http://stage.omatics.com/Images/Devices/Devices/10.png
http://stage.omatics.com/Images/Devices/Devices/20.png
--
--
http://stage.omatics.com/Images/Devices/Devices/350.png
```

at your desktop.

Hope this helps.